# Hibernate - Keeping Entities in sync with batch database updates

Tags: hibernate

Hi I was hoping to get some input on the following problem. I'm new to Hibernate and trying to piece the puzzle together for this.

Problem:  I have data in my database that is updated once a day. I want to keep my entities in sync with this and refresh them as well. I implemented a Spring/Quartz timer to call my hibernate implementation class to go and refresh the entities. I'm trying to ensure that each time this method is called that it clears all the current entities so they can be refreshed.  What would be the best approach for this?

Using Hibernate 3.2 Integrated with Spring.

Proposed Solution:

1. Is this where I would use the entity manager to manage them?

I tried using on the the Session.flush command and SesionFactory clear but it didn't work.

Spring/Hibernate Configuration

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd">


    <!--     Defines the hibernate session factory to be used by the hibernate support dao classes -->
    <bean id="hibernateSessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean" >
        <property name="dataSource" ref="webDataSrc" />
        <property name="annotatedClasses"> 
                <list> 
                        <value>test.foo</value> 
                </list> 
        </property>

        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="debug">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cglib.use_reflection_optimizer">false</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- get the datasource from the context -->
    <bean id="webDataSrc" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean" lazy-init="true">
        <property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/datasource"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="daoTxTemplate" abstract="true"
        class="org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionProxyFactoryBean">
        <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
        <property name="transactionAttributes">
            <props>
                <prop key="get*">
                    PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_READ_COMMITTED
                </prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean name="openSessionInViewInterceptor"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewInterceptor">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="hibernateSessionFactory" />
        <property name="singleSession" value="true" />
    </bean>
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="hibernateSessionFactory"/>
        <property name="nestedTransactionAllowed" value="true" />

    </bean>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do a couple of things here.  I would recommend using the `Query.setCacheMode(CacheMode.REFRESH)` if your using query cache.  This will force the refresh of the entities during the query.

[Hibernate Documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/performance.html) acutally states ...

> This is particularly useful in cases where underlying data may have
>   been updated via a separate process

You could also use `SessionFactory.evictQueries()` but this will remove all the query cache, which may be overkill.

Lastly, you could also use the `EntityManager.refresh(entity)` to reload a specific entity if it's known.

Comment: @Micheal - I will the Query.setCacheMode(CacheMode.REFRESH) . However I noticed I was getting a #org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Hibernate Session bound to thread, and configuration does not allow creation of non-transactional one here# . To setup a new transaction tied to the java thread, I have to explicity use the beginTransaction correct? or I would I be able to do that through the SessionFactory defined above?

Comment: It looks like your using a transaction manager so you should be able to use the @Transactional annotation on you method calls that perform transactions.  Check out the documentation for Spring transactions.  This will open and close the transactions so you don't have to manage them.

Comment: Ya I implemented the @Transactional annotation. Very nice and clean. Nice not having to use beginTransaction,close,finally's all over the code.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you keeping your Hibernate sessions open so long? They should not be opened for a day or longer. You should open the session, read data, do your thing and then close the session. If you need to keep data between sessions, you should use your own cache.

You are keeping some audit trail in your database when those daily updates are completed, right? So, every time you open your Hibernate session, check whether your internal cache is up to date. If the data in the database had been updated since the cache was populated, dump the cache and reload.

Comment: I disagree.  I don't think he is leaving the session open but the entities are sticking in the first or second level cache.

Comment: @Michael J. Lee: The first level cache dies with the Hibernate session. The second level cache is used less frequently so I assumed OP would mention if he or she was using it.

Comment: Thanks, you are correct.  I should have said query cache and not first level cache. (+1 for u!)

Comment: yep.  I see the question was edited to include the openSessionInViewInterceptor...

Comment: @Olaf - I included my spring/hibernate configuration above. The setup I am trying to using the TransactionProxyFactoryBean for the transaction manager. This will allow me to avoid having to use "beginTransaction", "closeTransaction" , and check using finally for closes. It ties the transactions to the java thread itself. I think my issue is that I am not retrieving a new transaction properly. I think Michael J. Lee has the right idea. However I need to retrieve a new transaction instance tied to my spring/quartz batch call, I think through calling the application context explicitly.

Comment: @Olaf - sorry to answer your question. I don't have a update as the tables in questions are truncated and reloaded completely. I just want to execute the spring/quartz thread that calls the method to refresh all of the entities. I will try SessionFactory.evictQueries() suggested below. I'm just running into the transaction thread error I mentioned in Michael question below.